# Repository with no license declaration and a single contributor, who isn't the owner

Tags: licensing, license

I am in touch with the one contributor of this project. The owner seems to be absent and there is no license. The only contributor is the developer I am in touch with. Would all of the copyright go to the developer or is there shared copyright with the owner?

Just to further clarify: 100% of all code has been written by the developer and no lines of code have been committed by the owner.

Comment: Is (or was) the contributor an employee or contractor of the owner? In what sense is/was the unreachable owner understood to be the "owner" of this project?

Comment: To be clear: repositories have absolutely nothing to do with licensing.